# Can not post form with many (over 256) values

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, embedded-jetty, embedded-tomcat-8

I am using Spring Boot 1.2.2 with Thymeleaf.
My Problem is I try to post a long list of Items (some labels, one checkbox) in a form, which cant be perform so many items of my list. (I tested small lists and it worked.)

First I used jetty but got an error, which says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Form too many keys
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeUtf8To(UrlEncoded.java:526)
```

I searched and saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998834/webapp-with-embedded-jetty-giving-exception/23012618#23012618). As the result I added

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormKeys=8000"]
```

to my gradle.build, but it didnt work out. As the result I switched to Tomcat and it fails again. The errormessage is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 256, Size: 256
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
```

looks like it can only perform 256 entries. I have about 500 entries. So I thought increasing the maxhttpheadersize would help and added this line to my application.properties:

```
server.tomcat.max-http-header-size=-1
```

(-1 as no limit) I set method="post" in my Thymeleaf form. Any other way to increase the 256 limit ? I dont want to paginate my result. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a quick comment. I am using Spring Boot 1.3.3 and when I set server.tomcat.max-http-header-size=0 it does not actually change the configuration.  Stepping through the code, that means to use the default, which is 8192.  I set it to a large value 65536 and that worked.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this is related to `AutoGrowCollectionLimit` in Spring, try to include this code in your controller in order to increase it:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAutoGrowCollectionLimit(768);
}
```

Check [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/119266-setautogrowcollectionlimit-more-than-256-records) thread in Spring forum, also in the official documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#setAutoGrowCollectionLimit-int--more-than-256-records).