# spring webflow submit array with new items

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I'm trying to submit array with new items using spring webflow. For eaxmple if myList has size 3 and then i add 4th item then submit fails.

```
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="item" varStatus="status">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <input type="number" readonly class="form-control" value="${item.a}" name="myList[${status.index}].a"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" value="${item.b}" name="myList[${status.index}].b"/>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-trash delete" data-link="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=deleteItem&itemId=${item.id}"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach> 

<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="number" readonly class="form-control" value="1234" name="myList[3].a"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="5678" name="myList[3].b"/>
  </td>
  <td class="text-center">
    <i class="fa fa-trash delete"></i>
  </td>
</tr>
```

So how to submit such form?

Answer (score 1):

because the ArrayList you are providing the databinder has a predefined fixed size and cannot accept new entries.

You need to wrap your ArrayList with an AutoPopulatingList (located in spring-core.jar) before attempting to add any new entries to the data binder in your flows.... (or simply use an AutoPopulatingList on your pojo to avoid wrapper method).

**Sample conversion method:**

```
import org.springframework.util.AutoPopulatingList;
```

//class definition skipped

```
        public <T> List<T> wrapListWithAutoPopulatingList(List<T> list, Class<?> pojoClazz)  {

            List<T> apl = new AutoPopulatingList(list, pojoClazz ) ;
            return apl;
        }
```

**Java Doc:**

> Simple List wrapper class that allows for elements to be automatically
>   populated as they are requested. This is particularly useful for data
>   binding to Lists, allowing for elements to be created and added to the
>   List in a "just in time" fashion.
>
> Note: This class is not thread-safe. To create a thread-safe version,
>   use the java.util.Collections.synchronizedList utility methods.
>
> Inspired by LazyList from Commons Collections.

**Also**, please be aware of the '**autoGrowCollectionLimit**' property on the initBinder. The default max value is 256 entries. This can be adjusted if you need more (or less). See

[Can not post form with many (over 256) values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811498/can-not-post-form-with-many-over-256-values/28821726#28821726)

Comment: where do we have to add this wrapListWithAutoPopulatingList method?