# Spring web flow form binding append to list

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I'm learning to use Spring, Spring Webflow and Thymeleaf. I created a little old school wizard application where the user have to fill out some forms click the next button and at the end that was a configuration process. Every `view-state`'s model is called `Configuration` which is my model class. This class contains a `List<Note> notes`. On every view-state the user has an option to add some notes. Now my issue is that with the form binding at every view-states this note list will be replaced instead of appended with the new note.

How can i append to this list instead of replace it at every view-state?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** A standard java collections ArrayList is initialized with a *FIXED* size and cannot be appended to with *NEW* entries/pojos.

So if you want to bind/append new entries to a collection you need to use the

```
import org.springframework.util.AutoPopulatingList;
```

Instead of a standard

```
java.collections.List
```

See this answer I wrote on a similar question for more details:

[spring webflow submit array with new items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910692/spring-webflow-submit-array-with-new-items/30925080#30925080)