# Spring webflow doesn't hold the value of object's field

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

i have created a simple webflow.

[image]

It has two steps. In the first step you must input the name of group and in the second one contact information. The contact is added to group when you click on `add contact`. By click then on `save group` the group must be saved. Practically it works, but i meet only one issue i can't understand. The instance of `EmailGroupForm` contains in the collection all `ContactForm,` but each `ContactForm` has empty fields.

here is the class diagram:

[image]

I have debugged at the method, where the `ContactForm` is added to `EmailGroupForm`. All `ContactForm` are initialized. I have noted, that in each method, there is different instance of `ContactForm`. I think it is the reason of issue, but i am not sure. I don't understand where is my thought error.

Please to help

The project `tutorial.spring4-tiles-simple-webflow` is in [gihub](https://github.com/oleg-duvanayev/common.issues.git)

Answer (score 0):

I think the default spring webflow binder is having trouble mapping the form fields to complex map type Map  after you click submit/save

Try changing

**from:**

```
public class OrderForm implements Serializable {

    private Map <Book, Integer> selectedBooks = new HashMap<Book, Integer>();
```

**To:**

```
    import org.springframework.util.AutoPopulatingList;

    public class OrderForm implements Serializable {

private AutoPopulatingList<Book> selectedBooks = new AutoPopulatingList<Book>(Book.class)

...
```

See this answer I wrote on a similar question for more details:

[spring webflow submit array with new items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910692/spring-webflow-submit-array-with-new-items/30925080#30925080)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @student upon further analysis this might be a variable scoping issue. Try changing 'flowScope.contactForm' -> 'viewScope.contactForm' I think and make sure you are init ContactForm everything you enter the view to add new contact.

Comment: YES, thank's for the idea! I did move the call `groupController.createNewContact()` from my `<view-state id=start ...>` to the next state `<view-state id="addNewContact"` into `<on-render>`. And now it works.